# I'm having problems with the implementation of sockets in my program

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a single program that simulates the game "Battleships", acting as both server and client.

In the menu I choose whether to play as a server (I call the server's Start method, a console opens and I go to the game screen) or as a client (I go to the game screen).

I run the program twice, the first time selecting server and the second time selecting client.

The first interface works fine, the problem I have with the second one is that it doesn't send all the messages to the server correctly and it doesn't receive any replies.

I attach my code here:

SERVER.cs

```
namespace Battleship_sockets
{
    public class Server
    {        
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        public TcpListener tcpListener;
        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        public bool dcc = false;
        // Lista de clientes conectados
        List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();

        // Instancia de ClientManager
        private ClientManager clientManager;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();
        #endregion

        public Server()
        {
            clientManager = new ClientManager(clients);
        }

        public async Task Start()
        {
            AllocConsole(); // Agregar esta línea para crear una consola en modo Windows Forms
            try
            {
                // Crear el punto de conexión para escuchar
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new(ipAddress, 8080);

                // Crear el socket TCP para escuchar
                tcpListener = new(localEndPoint);

                // Iniciar la escucha del socket
                tcpListener.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Server started and listening on port 8080...");

                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    Add(client);
                    // Iniciar un hilo para manejar la conexión del cliente
                    await HandleClient(client);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            await using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            try
            {
                #region 1
                // Leer mensajes del servidor
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine($"- Client{clientManager.GetClientes().Count}: {message}");

                // Verificar si hay dos clientes conectados
                if (clientManager.GetClientes().Count == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Both clients connected.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Ready to play...");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for another client to connect...");
                }

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Client error: {e.Message}");

                // Eliminar el cliente de la lista de clientes
                clientManager.RemoveClient(client);

                // Cerrar la conexión con el cliente
                client.Close();
            }
        }

        public void Ready()
        {
            try
            {
                while (clientManager.GetClientes().Count != 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No other client is connected.");
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"The player {clientManager.GetClientes().Count} is ready.");
                dcc = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Add(TcpClient client)
        {
            clientManager.AddClient(client);
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected clients: {clientManager.GetClientes().Count}");
            
        }

        public void Remove(TcpClient client)
        {
            clientManager.RemoveClient(client);
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected clients: {clientManager.GetClientes().Count}");
        }


    }
}
```

CLIENT.cs

```
namespace Battleship_sockets
{
    public class Client
    {
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        public TcpClient tcpClient;
        private NetworkStream stream;
        // Instancia de ClientManager
        private readonly ClientManager clientManager;
        #endregion

        public Client(ClientManager clientManager)
        {
            this.clientManager = clientManager;
        }

        public void Connect(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                Server sv = new Server();
                //Task.Run(() => sv.Add(tcpClient));

                // Conectar al servidor
                tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
                stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

                // Enviar datos al servidor
                string mensaje = $"Hi, Im {name}";
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensaje);
                stream.Write(buffer);

                // Leer respuesta del servidor
                byte[] bufferAnswer = new byte[1024];
                int answerLength = stream.Read(bufferAnswer, 0, bufferAnswer.Length);
                string answer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferAnswer, 0, answerLength);
                Console.WriteLine($"- Server: {answer}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
        }

        public void Send(string mensaje)
        {
            try
            {
                // Enviar datos al servidor 
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensaje);
                stream.Write(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            try
            {
                Server sv = new Server();
                Task.Run(() => sv.Remove(tcpClient));
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

MENU.cs

```
namespace Battleship_sockets
{
    public partial class MainMenu : Form
    {
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        private Server s;
        private Form1? form1;
        private readonly ClientManager clientManager;
        #endregion
        public MainMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            s = new Server();
        }

        private void btnServidor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => s.Start());
            form1 = new Form1();
            this.Hide(); // oculta el formulario actual
            form1.ShowDialog(); // muestra el nuevo formulario como cuadro de diálogo modal
            this.Close(); // cierra el formulario actual cuando se cierre el nuevo formulario
        }

        
        private void btnCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form1 = new Form1();
            form1.ShowDialog(); 
            this.Close();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Form1.cs

```
namespace Battleship_sockets
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region ATTRIBUTES
        public Client c;
        public Server s;
        private ClientManager clientManager;
        private List<Ship> ships = new List<Ship>();
        private int totalShips = 3;
        private int addedShips;
        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateButtons();
            c = new Client(clientManager);
            s = new Server();
            btnReady.Enabled = false;
            btnAddShip1.Enabled = false;
            btnAddShip2.Enabled = false;
            btnAddShip3.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
            btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;            
        }        
        private string GetRowLabel(int rowIndex)
        {
            const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            return alphabet[rowIndex].ToString();
        }
        private void CreateButtons()
        {
            int labelWidth = 20; // ancho de las etiquetas de fila y columna
            int labelHeight = 20; // altura de las etiquetas de fila y columna
            int buttonWidth = 25; // ancho de los botones
            int buttonHeight = 25; // altura de los botones
            // Agregar etiquetas para las columnas al panel
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            {
                Label lblCol = new Label();
                lblCol.Text = col.ToString();
                lblCol.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, 0);
                lblCol.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel1.Controls.Add(lblCol);
                lblCol = new Label();
                lblCol.Text = col.ToString();
                lblCol.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, 0);
                lblCol.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel2.Controls.Add(lblCol);
            }
            // Agregar etiquetas para las filas al panel
            for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
            {
                Label lblRow = new Label();
                lblRow.Text = GetRowLabel(row);
                lblRow.Location = new Point(0, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                lblRow.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel1.Controls.Add(lblRow);
                lblRow = new Label();
                lblRow.Text = GetRowLabel(row);
                lblRow.Location = new Point(0, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                lblRow.Size = new Size(labelWidth, labelHeight);
                panel2.Controls.Add(lblRow);
                // Agregar botones al panel
                for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Name = GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString();
                    button.Text = "";
                    button.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                    button.Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                    button.Enabled = false;
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    panel1.Controls.Add(button);

                    button = new Button();
                    button.Name = GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString();
                    button.Text = "";
                    button.Location = new Point((col + 1) * buttonWidth + labelWidth, (row + 1) * buttonHeight + labelHeight);
                    button.Size = new Size(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                    button.Enabled = false;
                    button.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(panel2_ButtonClick); // Agrega el controlador de eventos al botón
                    panel2.Controls.Add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        private void btnReady_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s.Ready();
            if (s.dcc)
            {
                // Habilitar los botones en el panel del oponente
                foreach (Control control in panel2.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is Button button)
                    {
                        button.Enabled = true;
                        button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                }
                // Deshabilitar el botón "Limpiar"
                btnClear.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Si no hay dos clientes conectados, mostrar un mensaje al usuario
                MessageBox.Show("Waiting for two clients to connect.", "Message",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
           
            
        }
        private void btnAddShip1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoordinatesForm form = new CoordinatesForm();
            Button button1 = (Button)sender;
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Point coordinates = form.Coordinates;
                // Comprobar que los botones correspondientes al barco elegido no estén ya ocupados por otro barco
                bool free = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    int row = coordinates.Y;
                    int col = coordinates.X + i;
                    Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                    if (button.BackColor != Color.White)
                    {
                        free = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Comprobar que el barco no se extienda fuera del tablero
                if (coordinates.X + 4 >= 10)
                {
                    free = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("The chosen location is not valid.");
                }
                if (free)
                {
                    Ship ship = new Ship(5, coordinates, true);
                    ships.Add(ship);
                    addedShips++;
                    // Pintar los botones correspondientes al barco en el panel1
                    for (int i = 0; i < ship.Size; i++)
                    {
                        int row = ship.Location.Y;
                        int col = ship.Location.X + i;
                        Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                        button.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The chosen location is not valid.");
                }
            }
            if (addedShips == totalShips)
            {
                btnReady.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        private void btnAddShip2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoordinatesForm form = new CoordinatesForm();
            Button button1 = (Button)sender;
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Point coordinates = form.Coordinates;
                // Comprobar que los botones correspondientes al barco elegido no estén ya ocupados por otro barco
                bool free = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    int row = coordinates.Y;
                    int col = coordinates.X + i;
                    Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                    if (button.BackColor != Color.White)
                    {
                        free = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Comprobar que el barco no se extienda fuera del tablero
                if (coordinates.X + 2 >= 10)
                {
                    free = false;
                }
                if (free)
                {
                    Ship ship = new Ship(3, coordinates, true);
                    ships.Add(ship);
                    addedShips++;
                    // Pintar los botones correspondientes al barco en el panel1
                    for (int i = 0; i < ship.Size; i++)
                    {
                        int row = ship.Location.Y;
                        int col = ship.Location.X + i;
                        Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                        button.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The chosen location is not valid.");
                }
            }
            if (addedShips == totalShips)
            {
                btnReady.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        private void btnAddShip3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoordinatesForm form = new CoordinatesForm();
            Button button1 = (Button)sender;
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Point coordinates = form.Coordinates;
                // Comprobar que los botones correspondientes al barco elegido no estén ya ocupados por otro barco
                bool free = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    int row = coordinates.Y;
                    int col = coordinates.X + i;
                    Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                    if (button.BackColor != Color.White)
                    {
                        free = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Comprobar que el barco no se extienda fuera del tablero
                if (coordinates.X + 3 >= 10)
                {
                    free = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("The chosen location is not valid.");
                }
                if (free)
                {
                    Ship ship = new Ship(4, coordinates, true);
                    ships.Add(ship);
                    addedShips++;
                    // Pintar los botones correspondientes al barco en el panel1
                    for (int i = 0; i < ship.Size; i++)
                    {
                        int row = ship.Location.Y;
                        int col = ship.Location.X + i;
                        Button button = (Button)panel1.Controls.Find(GetRowLabel(row).ToString() + col.ToString(), true)[0];
                        button.BackColor = Color.MediumPurple;
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The chosen location is not valid.");
                }
            }
            if (addedShips == totalShips)
            {
                btnReady.Enabled = true;
            }
        }                
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QuitShips();
            btnAddShip1.Enabled = true;
            btnAddShip2.Enabled = true;
            btnAddShip3.Enabled = true;
            btnReady.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void QuitShips()
        {
            foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button button)
                {
                    button.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            foreach (Control control in panel2.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button button)
                {
                    button.Enabled = false;
                    button.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
                }
            }
        }
        private void panel2_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            foreach (Control control in panel2.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button btn)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            c.Send(button.Name.ToString());
            button.Enabled = false;
        }        
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUser.Text != "")
            {
                c.Connect(txtUser.Text);
                lblMyShips.Text = $"{txtUser.Text}'s ships";
                btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
                btnAddShip1.Enabled = true;
                btnAddShip2.Enabled = true;
                btnAddShip3.Enabled = true;
                btnClear.Enabled = true;
                btnConnect.Enabled = false;
                txtUser.Enabled = false;
                lblError.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Error logging in, you must enter a user.";
            }
        }        
        private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c.Disconnect();
            btnReady.Enabled = false;
            btnAddShip1.Enabled = false;
            btnAddShip2.Enabled = false;
            btnAddShip3.Enabled = false;
            btnClear.Enabled = false;
            addedShips = 0;
            QuitShips();
            btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
            txtUser.Enabled = true;
            txtUser.Text = "";
            lblMyShips.Text = "My ships";
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENTMANAGER.cs

```
namespace Battleship_sockets
{
    public class ClientManager
    {
        private readonly List<TcpClient> clients;

        public ClientManager(List<TcpClient> clients)
        {
            this.clients = clients;
        }

        public void AddClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            clients.Add(client);
            Console.WriteLine($"Client{GetClientes().Count} is connected.");
        }

        public void RemoveClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Client{GetClientes().Count} it has disconnected..");
            clients.Remove(client);
        }
        public List<TcpClient> GetClientes()
        {
            return clients;
        }

    }
}
```

SHIP.cs

```
public class Ship
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public bool Horizontal { get; set; }
    public int Celdas { get; set; }  

    public Ship(int size, Point location, bool horizontal)
    {
        Size = size;
        Location = location;
        Horizontal = horizontal;
    }
}
```

COORDINATES.cs

```
namespace Battleship_sockets
{
    public partial class CoordinatesForm : Form
    {
        public CoordinatesForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtRow.Select();
        }
        public Point Coordinates { get; set; }
        private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtRow.Text != "")
            {
                char row = char.ToUpper(txtRow.Text[0]); // convertir la letra introducida en mayúsculas
                int col = (int)numericUpDownColumn.Value;
                Point coordinates = new Point(col, row - 'A');
                this.Coordinates = coordinates;
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Row field cannot be empty";
            }
        }
        private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
        private void txtRow_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // Si el texto ya tiene un carácter, cancela la tecla pulsada
            if (txtRow.Text.Length >= 1 && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            // Si la tecla pulsada no es una letra de la A a la J o la tecla de retroceso, cancela la tecla pulsada
            if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar < 'A' || e.KeyChar > 'J') && (e.KeyChar < 'a' || e.KeyChar > 'j') && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried several ways and can't find the solution.
Due to company requirements, TCP must be used and the server must be in the same client program.
[CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBzMX.png)

Comment: You don't await any of those Tasks. That could be _a_ problem.

Comment: Having `GetClientes()` does not make any sense.

Comment: Is this code really the smallest possible program that demonstrates the problem? Or could you remove some parts of it, and still have the problem?

Comment: All the parts are necessary for the game to work.

Comment: There's no code in `Client` that reads from the stream. Please update the code with what you have tried.

Comment: the client is already updated